# Why does org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty() strip commas?

Tags: java, css, dom, w3c

When I try to 'fix' this style, which is missing a comma, it strips it out again. Why does it do that and is there a way to put a comma in a style property?

```
    CSSStyleDeclaration style = da.getElementStyle((Element) n);
    String fontFamily = style.getPropertyValue("font-family");
    if (fontFamily != null && fontFamily.indexOf("Verdana") >= 0) {
        log.info("style: "+fontFamily);
        style.setProperty("font-family", "Verdana, sans-serif;", null);
        log.info("style: "+style.getPropertyValue("font-family"));
```

This is the log it generates:

```
Jan 20, 2014 4:34:52 PM com.onixnet.br.server.MailResource inlineCSS
INFO: style: Verdana sans-serif
Jan 20, 2014 4:34:52 PM com.onixnet.br.server.MailResource inlineCSS
INFO: style: Verdana sans-serif
```

It is not read-only. I can change it to another value like just 'sans-serif;'.

Reference: [http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSStyleDeclaration.html#setProperty_java.lang.String_*java.lang.String*_java.lang.String_](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSStyleDeclaration.html#setProperty_java.lang.String__java.lang.String__java.lang.String_)

Comment: What is da supposed to be?

Comment: `da` is `DOMAnalyzer da = new DOMAnalyzer(doc);` from [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net)